# How to impose a certain xunit trait

Tags: xunit

I am new to xunit and I would like to impose the following traits in all of the tests. The value of the trait Category can be either Unit or Integration. The value of Requirement trait can be anything as long as it is there. Tests are in located in different projects but in the same solution.

```
[Fact]
[Category, "Unit"]
[Requirement, "SomeRequirement"]
public void testMethod()
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the trait attribute.

```
Trait("Scope", "Unit")
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: You would use this like so: when your tests are compiled with traits, you can select tests based on traits in the test explorer in visual studio. you can sort by trait for filter. In the search bar in the test explorer, you could put 
Trait:"Unit"
and it would only show the tests with the trait of unit. Allowing you to run just those tests.